# Change navigation bar back button and remove title to make it appear like in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to remove back button title from my navigation bar and put a custom back button to make it appear as in ios7 (just a left arrow). I could change change the text, but when i change the text to nil, the previous page title appears again. Also changing the background image is not working too, though i could change the image

Comment: its not changing the back button title.. i can change the title of course, but i can't remove the title. On removing title,the default title appears again

Answer (score 4):

try this code to hide back button:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
```

create custom back button like this:

```
 CGRect frameimgback1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);
    UIButton *back = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimgback1];
    [back setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [back addTarget:self action:@selector(back)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  UIBarButtonItem *btnL = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:back];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnL;
```

Comment: this works. Is there any way that i could change the button in the appearance property of navigation bar ?

Comment: you want custom button or different apple button style ?

Comment: check this link
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: the thing is i have almost 20-25 view controllers. if i am setting a custom button, i need to implement this in all my view controllers. and also set selectors for all cases. All i need is button that has all the properties of the default back button. but it should appear as in ios7.